# Turn radio buttons into links by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, radio-button

I don't know what the specific name to this kind of form controller is (if there even is one), but basically I want to change radio elements like so;

```
<input type="radio" name="size" value="S" id="size_S" />
  <label for="size_S">S</label>
<input type="radio" name="size" value="M" id="size_M" />
  <label for="size_M">M</label>
<input type="radio" name="size" value="L" id="size_L" />
  <label for="size_L">L</label>
```

...into stylized links, the checked of which has a special class. For an example, I'd list the [size selection element on Macys.com](http://www1.macys.com/shop/product/stacy-adams-shoes-sandstorm-suede-plain-toe-chukka-boots?ID=597922&CategoryID=55637#fn=sp=1&spc=116&ruleId=3&slotId=2).

How can I turn the radios into these kinds of box links? Is there a library or plug-in that already does this?

I can modify the DOM, but the elements need to be radio buttons for the convenience of non-JS users.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pretty much reuse the standard form elements. With js enabled, hide the radio buttons, style the labels, and bind a `click` event to add the `active`/`selected` class. Clicking a label will still select the underlying radiobutton.

Example jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6BzY/

JS

```
$('input[type="radio"], label').addClass('js');

$('label').on('click', function() {
    $('label').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

CSS

```
input[type="radio"].js {
    display: none;
}

label.js {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

label.js.active {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ephram,

I visited the link you have provided and all I can see there are spans with a number in them for size selection. Did you mean those, or *like* those?

About you're question: I understand that the reason to show links instead of boxes would be the absence of js support. 
Have you considered using a  tag with hardcoded radio buttons in them and spans, like in your example, outside the noscript tags?

In any case, I don't really see the need to manipulate the DOM for this to be honest.

Comment: Actually, I want to have the radio buttons for noscript, and the Macys style boxes with jQuery. I'd like to accomplish this without needing to write basically the same DOM twice, i.e. using jQuery to replace the radio buttons with spans or whatever after the document has loaded.

Comment: Okay, I would recommend reading up on jQuery .each, basically that might be everything you need. Using .each you can isolate all the elements in the form and change them to whatever you'd like.